# Can I commit and push back to the repo after running a custom pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've created a custom pipeline that does work and then updates a state file in the git repo itself.

I'd like to commit this state change and then push the commit back to the repo, is that possible?

Comment: If you did that, wouldn't it kick off the pipeline again? What is the "state change" done by the pipeline?

Comment: Custom pipeline - so no.

Comment: The state is changes in a terraform state file that tracks cloud resources, I'm using the repo to manage the source code and the state file.  But it's not relevant; there's lots of other ways to do what I want to do - the question is about whether I can commit and push, not alternative ways to manage my state.